# Combining UITabController & UINavigation controller programmatically http://t.co/R52RlUL UITabController & UINavigation controller programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4

I have created a UItabbarcontroller and 2 views with UITableViews just using code (no IB stuff) and I want to now add a navigation bar at the top that will include add and edit buttons, however I seem to be tripping up and blowing my app up or adding navgation controller to a 3rd tab only.

Here is my main code for adding the tab bar and switching views

FYI -  I am using XCode4

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.mainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

// create the 2 views
tableViewController* vc1 = [[tableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController2* vc2 = [[tableViewController2 alloc] init];

// put them in an array
NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

// for the tab bar
mainTabBar.viewControllers = controllers;

// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[self.window addSubview:self.mainTabBar.view]; 

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want navigation controller(s)? You have to create one for each tab you want one in the UITabBarController.

You add a navigationController in conjunction with the first view controller on its stack. Try this:

```
// create the controllers for UITabBarController
tableViewController *vc1 = [[[TableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
navController *nav1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1] autorelease];

tableViewController *vc2 = [[[TableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
navController *nav2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2] autorelease];

// put them in an array
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nil];

// rest of your code
```

Also note that you need to release anything you alloc or retain. You can do it as I did by adding `autorelease` when you initialize them or you can release them explicitly after you've added them to the `controllers` array.

You then configure the `navigationItem` for each view controller in its `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` method depending on how you implemented it.

Comment: Thanks I added in load view the following but app builds ok but crashes out at the first nav controller 

`- (void)loadView
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
    
    
}

- (void)doSomething {
    
}`

Comment: That's a different problem. If you use `loadView` you need to initialize the view controller by creating and setting its view property. Because your VCs are UITableViewControllers, you must also set the tableView property. If you think you've done everything correctly, post your full `loadView` code and I'll take a look.

Comment: I believe I have set up tables ok as it works before adding navigationcontrollerv- code to follow

Comment: hey hey don't know what happened (but started again) and now working like a dream. should really take note of cocoa book I got that advises 10hours sleep a night !  Not got button on bar yet as it worked with nothing in loadView yet...

Comment: Glad you got it working. Check the Apple docs on programmatically creating a UIViewController for the requirements of your `loadView` implementation. Also, in your code sample in the comment you need to add `autorelease` to your `UIBarButtonItem`. As you have it, it will leak as it is retained twice. Once when you alloc, and again by the navigationItem.